# Have enum type of any tag in a class specialization

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums, class-template

How to have `enum` type of any tag in a class specialization?
as this works only for one ie. `L enum` :

```
enum class K 
{
   a, b, c, d, e
};
enum class L 
{
   a, c, e,
};

template<enum L>
struct J 
{
   constexpr static int N = static_cast<int>(L::e);
   int n[N] = { 7 };

   void print() 
   {
      cout << N << "\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
   J <L::e> obj;
   obj.print();
   return 0;
}
```

How to have it works as common such for `K` and any enum tag as long as it has the same **e** member name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can provide one more template argument, you can pass any `enum`s

```
template<typename Type, Type en>
struct J 
{
   // ...
}
```

and construct the object

```
J <K, K::e> obj;
obj.print();
```

**([See demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/v3Kq6N))**

---

Also checking the passed `Type` using [`std::is_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum), you can restrict the template types passed.